# Rails 3: How to setup associations for enrollment for children with a father, a mother, and up to two guardians?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

How to setup associations for enrollment for children with a father, a mother, and up to two guardians?

I know there are many ways to set this up, but how would you go about it? I'm not too sure how to setup the guardians. I'm currently thinking about two options, maybe you can recommend a 3rd one.

Option 1

```
Enrollments
belongs_to child
belongs_to father
belongs_to mother

Children
has_one enrollment
has_one father
has_one mother

Father
has_many enrollments
has_many children

Mother
has_many enrollments
has_many children
```

Option 2

```
Enrollments
has_and_belongs_to_many adults

Adults
has_and_belongs_to_many enrollments
has_many children
# would have a "relationship: father, mother, guardian"

Children
has_one enrollment
has_one father
has_one mother
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out has_many :through if I were you.

Adults

```
has_many children, :through => enrollments
```

Children

```
has many adults, :through => enrollments
```